# Limitations For Naming Of Data Attributes When Used With Tag Manager

Tags: html, google-tag-manager, custom-data-attribute

I've been using data attributes with Google Tag Manager to track clicks on specific links.

By creating a *Data Layer* variable and setting its name to the appropriate dot separated path, for example `gtm.element.dataset.alpha`, the name and value of the data attribute are made available in the variables attached to Link Clicks.

However today I encountered a data attribute that would always have a value of `undefined`.

To my surprise it appears to be that GTA will always return `undefined` for variables for data attributes that include additional dashes.

So the following data attribute will always have a value of `undefined`:

```html
data-alpha-bravo="example"
```

But these are fine:

```html
data-alpha="example"
data-alphabravo="example"
```

Using additional dashes is perfectly legal in data attributes, and I haven't managed to find any documentation related to additional dashes not being supported by GTA.

Is this correct or is there something else at work?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out you have to use camel-case for the variable name. So for a data attribute named `data-alpha-bravo`, the variable name would be:

```
gtm.element.dataset.alphaBravo
```

Comment: This is expected behaviour and has to do with Javascript more than GTM: "A custom data attribute name is transformed to a key for the DOMStringMap entry with the following rules: the prefix data- is removed (including the dash);
for any dash (U+002D) followed by an ASCII lowercase letter a to z, the dash is removed and the letter is transformed into its uppercase counterpart"  (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

Comment: @EikePierstorff Thanks for the additional information.